# Angular RxJS multiple Firebase calls to map a single Observable

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, firebase-storage, angularfire

I can't find the way to get this code working.

I want to get a list of products from firestore and for each one of them I have to make another call that returns that product URL.

I tried the following but of course I obtain an Observable in the new product property:

```
fillShopWithProducts(): void {
this.productsOb = this.productsService.getProducts()
.pipe(
  take(1), 
  switchMap(
    (products:Product[]) => {
      let newArrayOfProducts = products.map((product:Product) =>
       {
        return {
          ...product,
          imgUrlChanged:this.getProductUrl(product)
        }
       });           
       return newArrayOfProducts;     
    }),    
  finalize(()=> {
    this.shopIsLoading = false;       
  })
);
```

Here is the function that returns an Observable with the Product URL:

```
getProductUrl(product:Product): Observable<string> { 
  const ref = this.angularFireStorage.ref(`shopImages/${product.imgUrl}`);
  return ref.getDownloadURL();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just mapping the products array to an array containing the observable, you should use `forkJoin` in order to wait for all observables to complete before mapping the result to the enriched version of the product:

```
function fillShopWithProducts(): void {
  this.productsOb = this1.productsService
    .getProducts()
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((products: Product[]) =>
        forkJoin(
          products.map((product) =>
            this
              .getProductUrl(product)
              .pipe(
                map((productUrl) => ({ ...product, imgUrlChanged: productUrl }))
              )
          )
        )
      ),
      finalize(() => {
        this.shopIsLoading = false;
      })
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Ir worked perfectly. I thought that you needed a .pipe() to use a RxJS operator

Comment: Well, you can use pipe operators if you already have an observable, where you want to do stuff for each emitted value. But creational operators like `forkJoin`, `zip`, `combineLatest`, etc. are used to create a new observable which you then can pipe.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain brotha!